# Github Actions: xcpretty is not found despite being installed

Tags: ios, rubygems, github-actions, xcodebuild

I'm trying to replace our iOS project's horrible Jenkins setup with Github Actions. I think I have all the pieces in place, but I'm getting a failure I don't understand. In the step where I run `xcodebuild` to build and test the app, I'm getting an error that `xcpretty` is an unknown command, despite being installed via bundler in a previous step. Here are the relevant files:

build-and-run.yml

```
---
name: Build & Test
on:
  # Run tests when a PR merges.
  push:
    branches:
      - develop

  # Run tests when PRs are created or updated.
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]

  # Allow the workflow to be run manually.
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  DEVELOPER_DIR: /Applications/Xcode_12.app/Contents/Developer

jobs:
  test:
    name: Build & Test
    runs-on: 'macos-latest'

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Project
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: develop

      - name: Setup Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1.46.0
        with:
            ruby-version: 2.7.1

      - name: Restore Ruby Cache
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: vendor/bundle
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-gem-${{ hashFiles('**/Gemfile.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-gem-

      - name: Restore Pod Cache
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: Pods
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-pods-${{ hashFiles('**/Podfile.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-pods-

      - name: Bundle Install
        run: |
          bundle config path vendor/bundle
          bundle install --without=documentation --jobs 4 --retry 3

      - name: Install Cocoapods
        run: pod install --repo-update

      - name: Show Xcode Version
        run: xcode-select -p

      - name: Show Build Settings
        run: xcodebuild -workspace ./MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme 'MyApp-Test' -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11' -showBuildSettings

      - name: Test MyApp
        run: set -o pipefail && env NSUnbufferedIO=YES xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp-Test -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11' -enableCodeCoverage YES -derivedDataPath build/derived-data clean test | xcpretty -s

      - name: Run Danger
        env:
          DANGER_GITHUB_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.DANGER_GITHUB_API_TOKEN }}
        run: bundle exec danger
```

Gemfile (we don't use fastlane in the action, but I have to keep it in the Gemfile for now so the builds don't break on our Jenkins box):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.7.1'

gem 'cocoapods'
gem 'danger'
gem 'fastlane'
gem 'xcpretty'
gem 'danger-slather'
gem 'danger-swiftlint'
gem 'danger-xcode_summary'
gem 'xcpretty-json-formatter'

plugins_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'fastlane', 'Pluginfile')
eval_gemfile(plugins_path) if File.exist?(plugins_path)
```

In the `Bundle Install` step, the xcpretty gem is being installed:

```
Fetching xcpretty 0.3.0
Installing xcpretty 0.3.0
```

The `Install Cocoapods` step also works fine (probably because Cocoapods is pre-installed). When it gets to the `Test MyApp` step, the invocation creates an error:

```
Run set -o pipefail && env NSUnbufferedIO=YES xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp-Test -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11' -enableCodeCoverage YES -derivedDataPath build/derived-data clean test | xcpretty -s

/Users/runner/work/_temp/9d3633bf-6dae-45d7-a303-1c68abb63d53.sh: line 1: xcpretty: command not found
```

And then the workflow hangs for a very long time, so I usually cancel it. Any idea why `xcpretty` is not being found? My thought is, the directory where the gem is installed isn't in the search path, but I'm not sure about how I would do that. I'm sure there's a reasonable solution to this, but I'm having trouble finding it and am tired of banging my head against a wall.

Comment: Hi Joshua, have you found the answer to this one?

Comment: Yeah, I had to manually path to the ruby gem installation directory for it. It was brutal. I figure there must be a more elegant solution than that.

Comment: @JoshuaSullivan Hey an elaboration on the fix for this issue? We're now having this same issue with seemingly no changes to our Github actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, my solution was not at all tidy. I had to path into the gem installation directory and directly reference the gem executable. Thankfully, the relative path doesn't change, so I could just hardcode it into the test script. Maybe there's a more elegant solution, but once I got it working, I just dropped it.

And sorry if you're trying to reproduce this, but it was over a year ago and I left the company, so I don't have access to what the path was.

Answer (score 1):

1. I was facing the same issue while setting up `fastlane` to run my Xcode tests.
2. Finally, solved the issue by adding PATH in `Jenkinsfile` as below.
3. Note that `SampleProject-TestCase-Executions` is Sample app on my Desktop.
4. Please find [GitHub Demo App](https://github.com/BudhabhooshanPatil/Jenkin-demo-app) for more info.

```
node {
    stage "Run Fast file"    
    sh '''
    cd /Users/bhooshanpatil/Desktop/SampleProject-TestCase-Executions
    export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin$:"
    fastlane scan
    '''
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global properties -> Environment variables -> Name: LC_ALL, Value: en_US.UTF-8